# Laravel storing every email in database which is sent

Tags: php, laravel-5, swiftmailer

I want to store every email in the database which is sent from Laraval application. I tried to customize the email driver but it is too much hectic. Is there a clean way to achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

Hi i ran into similar problem. You dont need to customise the swiftmailer. There is package [here](https://github.com/shvetsgroup/laravel-email-database-log) which can do every thing that you want.

Here are some instruction. Use composer to install the package.

For **Laravel 5.5** or newer just run this two lines on your terminal:

```
composer require shvetsgroup/laravel-email-database-log

php artisan migrate
```

For **Laravel 5.4** or older:

```
 "shvetsgroup/laravel-email-database-log": "*"
```

Add to the provider in config/app.php

```
 ShvetsGroup\LaravelEmailDatabaseLog\LaravelEmailDatabaseLogServiceProvider::class,
```

Now, run this in terminal:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="ShvetsGroup\LaravelEmailDatabaseLog\LaravelEmailDatabaseLogServiceProvider" --tag="migrations"

php artisan migrate
```

you are all set.

Comment: is this package will do every thing.?

Comment: you just want to store the every email which is sent from you application?

Comment: i just want to store the every email which is sent so admin can see it later.

Comment: this will do the all. you can test it. if you want to know more let me know.